# Can't load WASM in the browser

Tags: javascript, error-handling, webassembly, emscripten

I'm using Windows 10 Pro
I have this `main.cpp` test file:

```cpp
#include <emscripten.h>

EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE
const char* testFunc(const char* parameter) {
    return parameter;
}
```

Then, I compiled using:

```bsh
em++ .\main.cpp -s WASM=1 -s EXPORTED_RUNTIME_METHODS='["ccall", "cwrap"]' -o data_converter.js
```

I copied the output files to my website directory:

```bsh
$website = "...";
Copy-Item .\data_converter.js ($website + "src\data\wasm\data_converter.js");
Copy-Item .\data_converter.wasm ($website + "src\data\wasm\data_converter.wasm");
```

Then, in `wasm-test.js`:

```js
async function fetchWasm(wasm) {
  const { data } = await axios(wasm, { responseType: "arraybuffer" });
  return data;
}

async loadWasm(wasmPath) {
  const bits = await fetchWasm(wasmPath);
  const worker = new Worker("wasm-worker.js");
  worker.postMessage({ bits });
  return new Promise((resolve) =>
    worker.addEventListener("message", resolve)
  );
}

async init() {
  console.log(await loadWasm("data/wasm/data_converter.wasm"))
}

init();
```

Then, `wasm-worker.js`:

```js
addEventListener("message", ({ data: { bits } }) => {
  WebAssembly.compile(bits).then((module) => {
    const instance = new WebAssembly.Instance(module);
    self.postMessage(instance);
  });
});
```

Eventually, I'm getting the error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: WebAssembly.Instance(): Imports argument must be present and must be an object
```

Answer (score 0):

The today's implementation of the WebAssembly.Instance [does not explicitly require](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAssembly/JavaScript_interface/Instance/Instance) the second argument (the imports object).

When Emscripten generates the .js file, inside there shall be the code to instantiate the instance, it is not expected to do that by a hand written code.